# Linux Kernel debugging scripts generate

Tags: linux, kernel

I want to use gdb debug the Linux kernel,So I open kernel debugging option and generate gdb script.After build the kernel,I found `vmlinux-gdb.py` in `/path/to/source/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py`.But when I try to append it to `~/.gdbinit`,an error occured as follow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xia0ji233/pwn/kernel/source/linux-5.8.1/vmlinux-gdb.py", line 34, in <module>
    import linux.proc
  File "/home/xia0ji233/pwn/kernel/source/linux-5.8.1/scripts/gdb/linux/proc.py", line 15, in <module>
    from linux import constants
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'linux' (/home/xia0ji233/pwn/kernel/source/linux-5.8.1/scripts/gdb/linux/__init__.py)
```

I found that there is no file named constants.py but constants.py.in.I have searched by google but no similar result.I will greatly appreciate if someone could give me some recommendations to solve this problem.

I firstly try to append this file in `/source/scripts/gdb/vmlinux-gdb.py`,but get module not fond error. I found that the pythonpath add in the file
`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/scripts/gdb")`
so I move this file to ../../ and again append it to my .gdbinit , Then I got an error as above.
I'm sure that I open the option generate gdb scripts when I build Linux kernel.